# fatal: engine already closed. Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: rest, mule, ssl-certificate, mule-studio

I am trying to connect to a REST service using certificates as it is a HTTPS call. I am getting the following error in while my service is trying to call the REST service :

```
[kafaka_test].http.requester.HTTPS_Request_Configuration.worker(2), WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
[kafaka_test].http.requester.HTTPS_Request_Configuration.worker(3), READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[kafaka_test].http.requester.HTTPS_Request_Configuration.worker(3), RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
[kafaka_test].http.requester.HTTPS_Request_Configuration.worker(3), fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fat
al alert: handshake_failure
[kafaka_test].http.requester.HTTPS_Request_Configuration.worker(3), fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fat
al alert: handshake_failure
```

Can anyone help with the cause and resolution of this? Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like Handshake exception, there could be problem with certificate which might not matching with your client side. Makesure keystores are correctly configured.Both in server and in your application.

Comment: @star .. But we have imported all the certificates on both sides .. it is working with SOAP UI and POSTMAN but not thru mulesoft